# How to read a JSON in Scala.js without parsing?

Tags: json, scala, scala.js

I'm new to Scala and Scala.js so I just code some lines and trying things:

I send a XMLHTTPRequest to openweathermap and get an JSON with some stuff in it.
Now i want to show some data on my website, so I need to pick some data out of the JSON (for example the temperature).
How do I do that? Do i really need a Class to parse it or can I just parse it to some generic Datatype? How do I get my data?
I tryed.

```
JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
```

But all I got was an *object [Object]* without any functions.

Comment: Off topic question - what made you choose Scala.js?

Comment: I like Java and always wanted to take deeper look in Scala. I´m not a big fan of JavaScript and so i though: give it a try. You could say: i like "exotic" technologies

Comment: Which JSON library you used? Circe?

Comment: I dont use any extern library. I import scala.scalajs.js.JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to introduce classes defining the shape of the parsed objects (not recommended), you can use the `js.Dynamic` values directly via a dot-syntax or a [`selectDynamic`](https://www.scala-js.org/api/scalajs-library/latest/scala/scalajs/js/Dynamic.html#selectDynamic(name:String):scala.scalajs.js.Dynamic) method:

```scala
import scala.scalajs.js.JSON

val res = JSON.parse("""
    {"key1": 1, "key2": 2}
""")
println(res.key1.asInstanceOf[Int]) // 1
println(res.selectDynamic("key2").asInstanceOf[Int]) // 2
```